# Limiting results in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables, `customers` (with columns  `A`, `B`) and `orders` (with columns `C`,`D`,`A`; the last one a foreign key).

This query returns the data I'm interested in:

```
SELECT customers.A, customers.B, orders.C, orders.D 
FROM customers, orders
WHERE customers.A = orders.A AND customers.B < 5 AND orders.D < 5
```

If I add `LIMIT 10`, I will get first ten 10 results (basically 10 orders), but what I want to do is to limit output based on the number of unique customers. So there would be exactly 10 unique customers in the result and therefore at least 10 - but likely more - orders. I think it's possible to do that with a subquery but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT c.A, c.B, orders.C, orders.D 
FROM (SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customers.B < 5 
      ORDER BY ....some-criteria... 
      LIMIT 10) c,
     orders
WHERE c.A = orders.A AND orders.D < 5
```

(Verified that sqlite successfully parses `LIMIT` in subqueries. Hopefully it doesn't ignore this `LIMIT` silently).

Comment: This will get 10 random customers, which might then be filtered out by the `c.B < 5` condition.

Comment: Thanks. Edited to filter customers in the subquery and suggest ORDER BY for getting non-random customers.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT customers.A, customers.B, orders.C, orders.D 
FROM customers, orders
WHERE customers.A IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT customers.A 
    FROM customers, orders
    WHERE customers.A = orders.A AND 
          customers.B < 5 AND 
          orders.D < 5
    LIMIT 10
) AND customers.A = orders.A AND orders.D < 5
```

Subquery select 10 distinct customers who have B < 5 and at least one order with D < 5. Main query selects all customers who were selected in subquery (I supposed A is ID) and their's orders with D < 5 (we do not need to check B again)